# Spring: get all Beans of certain interface AND type

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, autowired

In my Spring Boot application, suppose I have interface in Java:

```
public interface MyFilter<E extends SomeDataInterface>
```

(a good example is Spring's *public interface ApplicationListener< E extends ApplicationEvent >* )

and I have couple of implementations like:

```
@Component
public class DesignatedFilter1 implements MyFilter<SpecificDataInterface>{...}

@Component
public class DesignatedFilter2 implements MyFilter<SpecificDataInterface>{...}

@Component
public class DesignatedFilter3 implements MyFilter<AnotherSpecificDataInterface>{...}
```

Then, in some object I am interested to utilize **all filters** that implement MyFilter< SpecificDataInterface > **but NOT** MyFilter< AnotherSpecificDataInterface >

What would be the syntax for this?

Comment: If I may add to the question what if I want a list of all filters i.e. DesignatedFilter1, DesignatedFilter2, DesignatedFilter3 ?If I autowire List<MyFilter<SomeDataInterface>> , I get empty list. I am using Kotlin so can not use  List<MyFilter> Thanks.

Answer (score 138, accepted):

The following will inject every MyFilter instance that has a type that extends SpecificDataInterface as generic argument into the List.

```
@Autowired
private List<MyFilter<? extends SpecificDataInterface>> list;
```

Comment: I don't think you meant to put the "= new ArrayList<>();" on the end :)

Comment: Your correct, I removed it :). 
Extra info: It would still work with it.

Comment: Does Spring implementation read class bytecode to extract exact generic type? This info isn't available from objects directly due to type erasure... **I hate this Spring magic** if it takes place.

Comment: I believe the class that is performing this is https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/core/ResolvableType.java there is to my knowledge no byte code magic. This is just reflections.

Comment: Are you certain this works as expected considering there’s no reification?

Comment: There's a separate question on how Spring can read the generic type information: [How can Spring get generic type information during runtime regarding “Strongly-typed collection”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9650723/how-can-spring-get-generic-type-information-during-runtime-regarding-strongly-t)

Answer (score 27):

You can simply use

```
@Autowired
private List<MyFilter<SpecificDataInterface>> filters;
```

**Edit 7/28/2020:**

As Field injection is not recommended anymore [Constructor injection should be used instead of field injection](https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/tag/pitfall/RSPEC-3306)

With constructor injection:

```
class MyComponent {

  private final List<MyFilter<SpecificDataInterface>> filters;

  public MyComponent(List<MyFilter<SpecificDataInterface>> filters) {
    this.filters = filters;
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: You can use @RequiredArgsConstructor so you don't have to write the constructor code.

Comment: @Slim indeed it is an option. I prefer to use Lombok for demo and tutorials but not for production code.

Comment: As far as I know, @RequiredArgsConstructor should only run during compilation, so it shouldn't affect performance.

Answer (score 11):

In case you want a `Map<String, MyFilter>`, where the `key` (`String`) represents the bean name:

```java
private final Map<String, MyFilter> services;

public Foo(Map<String, MyFilter> services) {
  this.services = services;
}
```

which is the `recommended` alternative to:

```java
@Autowired
private Map<String, MyFilter> services;
```

Answer (score 10):

In case you want a map, below code will work. The key is your defined method

```
private Map<String, MyFilter> factory = new HashMap<>();

@Autowired
public ReportFactory(ListableBeanFactory beanFactory) {
  Collection<MyFilter> interfaces = beanFactory.getBeansOfType(MyFilter.class).values();
  interfaces.forEach(filter -> factory.put(filter.getId(), filter));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make public static map of singleton factory beans so that it can be accessed across all packages

```
@Component
public class ProcessorFactory {
public static Map<String, MyFilter > factory = new HashMap<>();

@Autowired
public void CreateFilterFactory(ListableBeanFactory beanFactory) {
    Collection< MyFilter> interfaces = beanFactory.getBeansOfType(MyFilter.class).values();
    interfaces.forEach(filter -> factory.put(filter.getSource(), filter));
}
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! What sets this apart from the other 4 answers already provided?