# Injecting Collection of Interface Type into Method Annotated with @Bean

Tags: java, spring

Using Spring and given several classes that implement a common interface, how would I reference all classes that implemented this interface using the `@Bean` annotation at the method level?

I want to retrieve all implementing instances, apply some logic to each instance, then return a managed `Map<String, Animal>` object which can be injected to other classes or components.

**Common Interface(s)**

```java
public interface Animal {

   String makeNoise();

}
```

```java
public interface Person {

   String getOccupation();

}
```

**Animal Implementation #1**

```java
public Dog implements Animal {

   @Override
   String makeNoise() {
      return "Bark! Bark!";
   }

}
```

**Animal Implementation #2**

```java
public Cat implements Animal {

   @Override
   String makeNoise() {
      return "Meow! Meow!";
   }

}
```

**Person Implementation #1**

```java
public Developer implements Person {

   @Override
   public String getOccupation() {
      return "Software Engineer";
   }

}
```

**Person Implementation #2**

```java
public Lawyer implements Person {

   @Override
   public String getOccupation() {
      return "Litigator";
   }

}
```

**Configuration**

```java
@Configuration
public class Initialize {

   //<snip> Beans created for Developer, and Lawyer objects </snip>

   @Bean
   Map<String, Developer> getDevelopers(List<Developer> developers) { // This is fine
      return new HashMap<>(...);
   }

   @Bean
   Map<String, Lawyer> getLawyers(List<Person> people) { // Spring wires this dependency fine
      return new HashMap<>(...);
   }

   @Bean
   Map<String, Dog> getOwners(Map<String, Person> owners) { // Spring reports it cannot auto-wire this dependency
                                                            // what do I do here? 
   }

}
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You need a Bean with type `List<Animals>` to be present in the context at runtime. Only then can the dependency for the bean you want be satisfied.

Comment: @rdas Is that really the only way in Spring? I want to leverage runtime scanning of the class path to automatically pick up the implementing classes.

Comment: Simplest way would be to have a `@Bean` method that does the same thing.

Comment: Looks like it may be a duplicate of this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40286047/spring-get-all-beans-of-certain-interface-and-type

Comment: Found the answer with y’alls help, I’ll update the question and provide an answer when I get home. Basically leveraged covariance and a List to convince Spring to wire all classes/beans to that List

Comment: You have 2 maps adhering to the `Map<String, Person>` contract and normally the `Map<String, <type>>` is handled in a special way by Spring. So what is it you want. Please add the error message you get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to leverage co-variance with a `List`. See below pseudo-code/code snippet.

```java
@Configuration
public class Initialize {

   //<snip> Beans created for Developer, and Lawyer objects </snip>

   @Bean
   Map<String, Developer> getDevelopers(List<Developer> developers) {
      return new HashMap<>(...);
   }

   @Bean
   Map<String, Lawyer> getLawyers(List<Person> people) {
      return new HashMap<>(...);
   }

   @Bean
   Map<String, Dog> getOwners(List<Map<String, ? extends Person>> owners) { // Spring will auto-wire the "owners" variable 
                                                                            // with all bean objects that match this signature 
                                                                            // (✅ Map<String, Lawyer>, ✅ Map<String, Developer> ...)

   }

}
```

Resources:

- [Spring: get all Beans of certain interface AND type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40286047/spring-get-all-beans-of-certain-interface-and-type)

Answer (score 0):

Try this kind of configuration. The only point here is that the order of beans in the collection is random and can't be under control.

```java
    @Configuration
    public class CollectionConfig {

        @Bean
        public Animal getCat() {
            return new Cat();
        }

        @Bean
        public Animal getDog() {
            return new Dog();
        }

        @Bean
        Map<String, Animals> gatherAnimals(List<Animals> animals) {
           // any code
        }
    }
```

Here is more about that https://www.baeldung.com/spring-injecting-collections