# Object inheritance - refactoring problem - possibility to create flexible service

Tags: java, spring, refactoring

It should be pretty easy but obviously I am lacking of basic knowlege.
I have a service which is ment to create ticket in `BugTracking` systems.
Creating plugins is pretty stright forward. there is an interface

```
public interface BugTracker {
    boolean createAndSendIssue(Issue issue);
    boolean updateAndSendIssue(Issue issue);
    boolean closeIssue(Issue issue);
}
```

and API client for JIRA:

```
@Component
public class JiraClient implements BugTracker {
    @Override
    public boolean createAndSendIssue(Issue issue) {
        //Logic for using JIRA REST API
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean updateAndSendIssue(Issue issue) {
        //Logic for using JIRA REST API
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean closeIssue(Issue issue) {
        //Logic for using JIRA REST API
        return false;
    }
}
```

API CLient for Bugzilla:

```
@Component
public class BugzillaClient implements BugTracker {

    @Override
    public boolean createAndSendIssue(Issue issue) {
        //Logic for using BUGZILLA REST API
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean updateAndSendIssue(Issue issue) {
        //Logic for using BUGZILLA REST API
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean closeIssue(Issue issue) {
        //Logic for using BUGZILLA REST API
        return false;
    }
}
```

Problem occurs on the `Service` which is handling `MVC`. Piece of it looks like:

```
@Service
public class BugTrackerService {
    private final BugzillaClient bugzillaClient;
    private final JiraClient jiraClient;
    private static final String JIRA_TYPE = "Jira";
    private static final String BUGZILLA_TYPE = "Bugzilla";

    @Autowired
    BugTrackerService(BugzillaClient bugzillaClient, JiraClient jiraClient) {
        this.bugzillaClient = bugzillaClient;
        this.jiraClient = jiraClient;
    }

    boolean processIssueTicketRequest(Issue issue){
        if ( issue.getBugTrackerType().bugTrackingSystemType.name.equals(JIRA_TYPE)) {
            return jiraClient.createAndSendIssue(issue);
        } else if (issue.getBugTrackerType().bugTrackingSystemType.name.equals(BUGZILLA_TYPE)){
            return bugzillaClient.createAndSendIssue(issue);
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

is it somehow possible to create method `BugTrackerService.processIssueTicketRequest` without all clients autowired? At this moment it is not so much of a problem but after integrating with more and more systems this service will become complex.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on how reusable you want implementations to be, I'd probably put the logic of checking whether the given issue is of matching typing into the interface, eg

```
boolean canWorkWithGivenIssue(Issue issue);
```

With that in place then you don't need to know actual types of trackers you dispatch on, and merely aggregate them into the list. Spring will do that for you if you annotate a collection with @Autowired, in which cases it will provide you all the beans with matching type. Your service then could look like this

```
@Autowired List<BugTracker> trackers; //autowired on field for brevity

boolean processIssueTicketRequest(Issue issue){
    for (BugTracker t : trackers)
        if (t.canWorkWithGivenIssue(issue))
            return t.createAndSendIssue(issue);
    return false;
}
```

Comment: it looks great but I cant get how to Autowire such field. Autowire annotation on interface link all implementation to the list by default?

Comment: Autowire on list is treated specially, yes. from https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Autowired.html: `In case of an array, Collection, or Map dependency type, the container autowires all beans matching the declared value type`

Comment: knowlege about this will make my life so much easier :), thanks !

Comment: Similar problem/solution was here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40286383/11733759

Answer (score 2):

Turn the type into an `enum` and let the `BugTracker` decide if it can handle it. Then inject a collection of all `BugTracker` instances, iterate over them and if it supports the type call the appropriate method.

```
public enum SystemType { JIRA, BUGZILLA }
```

Then add a method, for instance `supports(Issue issue)`, to your `BugTracker`.

```
boolean supports(Issue issue);
```

In the implementations check if it can be handled, for instance in the `JiraClient` do something like this.

```
public boolean supports(Issue issue) {
  return JIRA == issue.getBugTrackerType();
}
```

Then in your `BugTrackerService` get a list of all `BugTracker` instances, iterate and call the appropriate one.

```
@Service
public class BugTrackerService {

    private final List<BugTracker> bugTrackers;

    BugTrackerService(List<BugTracker> bugTrackers) {
        this.bugTrackers=bugTrackers;
    }

    boolean processIssueTicketRequest(Issue issue){
        for (BugTracker bugTracker : this.bugTrackers) {
            if (bugTracker.supports(issue) ) {
                bugTracker.createAndSendIssue(issue);
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Now you are as flexible as you want to be and can support as many as you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass on the responsibility of finding out the correct implementation of `BugTracker` to a `BugTrackerFactory`.

```java
@Component
class BugTrackerFactory {

    @Autowired
    private final BugzillaClient bugzillaClient;
    @Autowired
    private final JiraClient jiraClient;

    private static final String JIRA_TYPE = "Jira";
    private static final String BUGZILLA_TYPE = "Bugzilla";

    public BugTracker getBugTracker(String type) {
        if (JIRA_TYPE.equals(type)) {
            return jiraClient;
        } else if (BUGZILLA_TYPE.equals(type)) {
            return bugzillaClient;
        } else {
            // throw some exception
        }
    }
}
```

BugTrackerService :

```java
@Service
public class BugTrackerService {
    private final BugTrackerFactory bugTrackerFactory;

    @Autowired
    BugTrackerService(BugTrackerFactory bugTrackerFactory) {
        this.bugTrackerFactory = bugTrackerFactory;
    }

    boolean processIssueTicketRequest(Issue issue){
        return bugTrackerFactory.getBugTracker(issue.getBugTrackerType().bugTrackingSystemType.name).createAndSendIssue(issue);
    }
}
```