# What is the best way to avoid chained if-else condition to invoke different class function?

Tags: spring-boot, oop, design-patterns

I am writing a GraphQL Query API which takes filter as input. Based on the filter I need to invoke different object function.

API function signature

```
public GrantsConnection fetch(GrantFilter filter)
```

GrantFilter has following attributes.

```
public class GrantFilter {
  private Boolean isPrimary;
  private String profileId;
  private String entityId;
}
```

The filter can be a combination of one or two or all attributes.

My approach

```
public GrantConnection(GrantFilter filter) {
  if(filter.getIsPrimary() != null
     && filter.getProfileId() == null
     && filter.getEntityId() == null) {
    // invoke a function
  } else if(filter.getIsPrimary() == null
     && filter.getProfileId() != null
     && filter.getEntityId() == null) {
     // invoke different function
  } else if(filter.getIsPrimary() == null
     && filter.getProfileId() == null
     && filter.getEntityId() != null
     // invoke 3rd function
  }
 // other combinations
}
```

All the function invoked from conditionals are objects which implement same interface.
What is the best way to write this in spring?

Answer (score 1):

I would create a custom `Filter` class that implements `Predicate<GrantFilter>`

```java
@RequiredArgsConstructor
class Filter implements Predicate<GrantFilter> {
    private final Predicate<Boolean> isPrimaryPredicate;
    private final Predicate<String> profileIdPredicate;
    private final Predicate<String> entityIdPredicate;

    @Override
    public boolean test(GrantFilter gf) {
        return isPrimaryPredicate.test(gf.getIsPrimary())
                && profileIdPredicate.test(gf.getProfileId())
                && entityIdPredicate.test(gf.getEntityId());
    }
}
```

Now, I would keep a collection of `pairs` of `Filter` and a function that converts a `GrantFilter` to your `GrantConnection` (this will allow to create show which function needs to be called in which situation in a declarative way):

```java
List<Pair<Filter, Function<GrantFilter, GrantConnection>>> connectionsByFilter = List.of(
        Pair.of(
                new Filter(Objects::nonNull, Objects::isNull, Objects::isNull), this::firstFunction
        ),
        Pair.of(
                new Filter(Objects::isNull, Objects::nonNull, Objects::isNull), this::secondFunction
        ),
        Pair.of(
                new Filter(Objects::isNull, Objects::isNull, Objects::nonNull), this::thirdFunction
        )
);
```

PS: feel free to rename some of the things or make the code a bit more concise.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @Emanuel. I was wondering what if the function which needs to be called takes 3 arguments. In my case the function signature is like this
`public GrantConnection fetch(TrustId trustId, GrantFilter filter, Pagination pagination)`

Comment: i should still work. are the additional params used by the firstFunction, secondFunction .. etc? or where exactly would be the problem?

Comment: Yes. The function which needs to be executed in each conditional has signature like this
`public GrantConnection fetch(TrustId trustId, GrantFilter filter, Pagination pagination)`
How would we create the `connectionsByFilter` list? Can you please help me with an example.

Answer (score 0):

I found the way here [Spring: get all Beans of certain interface AND type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40286047/spring-get-all-beans-of-certain-interface-and-type)

My implementation

```
public interface GrantService {
  boolean canBeInvoked(GrantFilter filter);

  GrantConnection fetch(GrantFilter filter);
}
```

I created multiple classes implementing the interface `GrantService`. One such example is

```
public GrantServiceByProfileId implements GrantService {
  @Override
  public boolean canBeInvoked(GrantFilter filter) {
    return filter.getProfileId() != null
      && filter.getIsPrimaryProfile() == null
      && filter.getEntityId() == null
  }

  @Override
  public GrantConnection fetch(GrantFilter filter) {
   // data layer implementation
  }
}
```

I created another class to get all the beans and iterate over the list and invoke the first service which returns `true` for `canBeInvoked()` function.

```
public class GrantServiceImpl {
  @Autowired
  private final List<? extends GrantService> grantServices;

  public GrantConnection fetch(GrantFilter filter) {
    for(GrantService gs: grantServices) {
      if(gs.canBeInvoked(filter)) {
        return gs.fetch(filter);
      }
    }
  }
}
```