# How to inject a custom ObjectFactory in Spring

Tags: java, spring

I'm injecting an `ObjectFactory` into a bean, to get a new object when required, like it is done in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6136261/how-to-produce-prototype-objects-from-singleton-design-help-needed) (see the accepted answer).

Now I need to start using a custom `ObjectFactory`, which gets a new object from the ApplicationContext and also does something else. Something like this:

```
@Component
public class MyDefenderObjectFactory implements ObjectFactory<Defender>, ApplicationContextAware
{
  private ApplicationContext appCtx;

  @Override
  public Defender getObject () throws BeansException
  {
    // Some other operation we need to run upon new object creation
    System.out.println ( "New Defender being returned" );
    return this.appCtx.getBean ( Defender.class );
  }

  @Override
  public void setApplicationContext ( ApplicationContext applicationContext ) throws BeansException
  {
    this.appCtx = applicationContext;
  }
}
```

My hope is that this factory is injected into the `defenderFactory` from the example linked above:

```
@Component
class DefenderBuilder implement VechicleBuilder 
{
  @Autowired
  ObjectFactory<Defender> defenderFactory;

  Defender build() {
     return defenderFactory.getObject()
  }
}

@Component @Scope("prototype")
class Defender {
...
}
```

However, Spring isn't using this class to inject an ObjectFactory bean into `defenderFactory`. How can it be done? I've also tried to add `@Qualifier ( "MyDefenderObjectFactory" )` to the field `defenderFactory` above, but no luck.

Comment: Show the code for `defenderFactory`.  Is `MyDefenderObjectFactory` in a package that Spring has been told to scan?

Comment: @JimGarrison defenderFactory comes from the example I've linked, I've extended my question to report its code too. Yes, my factory is being picked by Spring and I can see this in the log messages, but it's just put apart as a bean, not used for auto-injection.

Comment: You MUST include all relevant code in your question as off-site links go bad over time.  Please add the code for `defenderFactory` showing how you expect the injection to occur.

Comment: I've done it, despite the fact that I linked another SO question, so it's unlikely it goes away. I've also got a good answer by Oleg, see below.

Comment: I'm confused. Why not just declare the target of injection/auto-wiring as `MyDefenderObjectFactory defenderFactory;`> Then Spring will be able to inject by type.

Comment: @JoseQuijada, I don't remember the details, but you need this when defenderFactory can vary, depending on the configuration or the fact you use a jar with these annotations on another jar (eg, a final application) that defines its own factory. In such a case, the only thing you know is that you'll get an ObjectFactory that returns defenders, but you want to allow the consumers of your library or app to be able to tell which particular defender factory they want to use. So, you don't want to hardwire it to MyDefenderFactory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you can see [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework/spring-beans/4.2.0.RELEASE/org/springframework/beans/factory/support/DefaultListableBeanFactory.java#958) `ObjectFactory` resolution is hard coded and handled by Spring internally:

```
else if (ObjectFactory.class == descriptor.getDependencyType()) {
    return new DependencyObjectFactory(descriptor, beanName);
}
```

This means you can't get `MyDefenderObjectFactory` when you resolve by type, you can get it if you will resolve by name and for that you need to use the `Resource` annotation which resolves by name first:

```
@Resource(name="myDefenderObjectFactory")   
ObjectFactory<Defender> defenderFactory;
```

Comment: Thanks @Oleg. I'll go with this. I'd say the Spring hardcoding, if not a bug, is something that should be improved.

Comment: @zakmck Yes, I agree. At the very least this is extremely poorly documented.